# Multipart Post to Attachment

Tags: api, java, http, httppost

I am trying to send a binary file in Java to Salesforce '/sobject/Attachment' endpoint. Below is the code I am trying to use, but I keep receiving a 400 error. Any idea as to what the solution is?

```
public void postAttachmentToSalesforce(String campaignId, File upload) throws HttpException, IOException {

    // convert File to byte array
    byte[] byteFile = new byte[(int) upload.length()];
    FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(upload);
    fs.read(byteFile);
    fs.close();

    // encode byte[] as Base64 to send to SF
    byte[] encodedFile = Base64.getEncoder().encode(byteFile);

    JSONObject toPost = new JSONObject();
    toPost.put("Body", encodedFile);
    toPost.put("ParentId", campaignId);
    toPost.put("Name", upload.getName());   

    // open new multipart
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(authToken.getInstanceUrl() + versionUrl + "/sobjects/Attachment/");
    MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    post.addHeader("Authorization", "OAuth " + authToken.getAccessToken());
    post.addHeader("X-PrettyPrint", "1");
    post.addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

    builder.addBinaryBody("Body", encodedFile);

    builder.addTextBody("ParentId", campaignId);
    builder.addTextBody("Name", upload.getName());

    HttpEntity multi = builder.build();
    post.setEntity(multi);

    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
    System.out.println(response);
}
```

Here is the response:

```
HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request [Date: Fri, 23 Sep 2016 19:46:25 GMT, Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8, Transfer-Encoding: chunked] ResponseEntityProxy{[Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8,Chunked: true]}}
```

Comment: Do you have the debug output of the full URL this generates? (anonymized if you've got a My Domain URL) `authToken.getInstanceUrl() + versionUrl + "/sobjects/Attachment/"`

Comment: @MarkPond, here is the URL: https://cs43.salesforce.com/services/data/v34.0/sobjects/Attachment/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update - attempt #2**

I don't have a java environment to test with but I changed your provided code based on some other code I've got handy and I've got my fingers crossed.

I changed out the `MultipartEntityBuilder` for a `StringEntity` and then serialized the `JSONObject` which you already had but were not using. I also changed the method on the encoder to output a `String` to be included in the JSON body instead of the byte array.

```
public void postAttachmentToSalesforce(String campaignId, File upload) throws HttpException, IOException {

    // convert File to byte array
    byte[] byteFile = new byte[(int) upload.length()];
    FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(upload);
    fs.read(byteFile);
    fs.close();

    // encode byte[] as Base64 to send to SF
    String encodedFileAsString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeAsString(byteFile);

    JSONObject toPost = new JSONObject();
    toPost.put("Body", encodedFileAsString);
    toPost.put("ParentId", campaignId);
    toPost.put("Name", upload.getName());   

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(authToken.getInstanceUrl() + versionUrl + "/sobjects/Attachment/");
    post.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + authToken.getAccessToken());
    post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    StringEntity params = new StringEntity(toPost.toString(), "UTF-8");
    params.setContentType("application/json");
    post.setEntity(params);

    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
    System.out.println(response);
}
```

---

**Original response**

On first look, I would suspect that it is your `Authorization` header value being `OAuth` concatenated with the token instead of the usual `Bearer` and then the token.

Does this give you a different result?

```
 post.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + authToken.getAccessToken());
```

SFDC Docs: [REST API Insert or Update Blob data](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm)

Comment: Switching it to Bearer still returns a 400

Comment: @xtheking updated the answer with another possible solution.

Comment: Works! Marked it as the correct answer. Thank you so much.